# how to disable `show-mode-in-prompt` in PS2, PS3, PS4

Tags: prompt

I'm using two lines for `PS1`, and enabled `show-mode-in-prompt` in `.inputrc` as below:

- PS1 ( [dotfiles](https://github.com/marslo/dotfiles/blob/main/.marslo/.env#L232) )

  ```bash
  PS1="\n\[\033[1m\]\[\033[38;5;240m\]╭╶ (\u@\h\[\033[1m\] "
  PS1+="\[\033[0;31m\]\w\[\033[1m\]\[\033[38;5;240m\]) "
  PS1+="$(__git_ps1 \"- (\[\033[32;2m\]%s\[\033[0m\]\[\033[38;5;240m\]) \")\[\033[1m\]"
  PS1+="\[\033[38;5;240m\]`if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo \[\033[38\;5\;240m\]\-\>; else echo \[\033[0\;31m\]\↯; fi`\[\033[1m\]"
  PS1+="\n\[\033[38;5;240m\] $ \[\033[1m\]\[\033[0m\]"

  $ echo $PS1
  \n\[\033[1m\]\[\033[38;5;240m\]╭╶ (\u@\h\[\033[1m\] \[\033[0;31m\]\w\[\033[1m\]\[\033[38;5;240m\]) $(__git_ps1 "- (\[\033[32;2m\]%s\[\033[0m\]\[\033[38;5;240m\]) ")\[\033[1m\]\[\033[38;5;240m\]`if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo \[\033[38\;5\;240m\]\-\>; else echo \[\033[0\;31m\]\↯; fi`\[\033[1m\]\n\[\033[38;5;240m\] $ \[\033[1m\]\[\033[0m\]
  ```
- .inputrc ( [dotfiles](https://github.com/marslo/dotfiles/blob/main/.inputrc#L23-L30) )

  ```bash
  set emacs-mode-string   "\1\e[38;5;240;1m\2╰╶ ᓆ \1\e[0m\2\1\e[3 q\2"
  set vi-ins-mode-string  "\1\e[38;5;240;1m\2╰╶ \1\e[33;1m\2ᓎ \1\e[0m\2\1\e[5 q\2"
  set vi-cmd-mode-string  "\1\e[38;5;240;1m\2╰╶ \1\e[34;1m\2ᓏ \1\e[0m\2\1\e[4 q\2"
  set show-mode-in-prompt on
  ```

However, when it's running with PS2, it shows as below:
[image]

is there any solution to disable `show-mode-in-prompt` in PS2, PS3 and PS4 ?

btw, detail system info:

```bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.2.1
BuildVersion:       23C71

$ echo $TERM_PROGRAM
iTerm.app
```